# Asp.net MVC3 working on razor as well aspx view engine in parallel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to convert my views from aspx view engine to razor as we moving forward with new version of MVC, but it is hard to convert everything in single stretch as it is really huge,
is it possible to do it in parallel.

I mean does MVC allows to have few razor views as well as well aspx views and run with out any issues?,  or what would be the work around?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the MVC does allow you to mix ASPX views and Razor views on one project.

The framework is very flexible. I've been involved with a couple sites using both aspx and Razorviews. The reason was ALWAYS that they were moving from one to another.

In these cases the aspx pages were not mass changed. New pages were universally Razor and aspx pages were only converted when serious work or re-work was already being done to them.

**Followup**

there are many aspx to Razor converters. I don't recommend this approach but be aware this is Microsoft's app for convertion.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2bfd1ca-9808-417c-b963-eb1ea4896790

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/ ?

It looks promising.

It had some issues with included controls a time ago, but I'm not to updated.

Comment: I converted 200+ views in a couple of hours with this. Maybe I was lucky

Comment: This is the leading tool. Microsofts has very high reviews so at this point I may steer that way. In general, I've found that converting slowly grows a comfort level across an organization. Generated code is rarely smooth and always foreign to the users.